# mysqldump without database name

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to dump data in xml format without the database name in the output?

If I dump output like this with the --xml option:

```
$>mysqldump --xml my_database_name my_table > my_table.xml
```

Then my output is something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="my_database_name">
...
```

You can see the database name in the output which I do not want.

Is there an option to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such option for the mysqldump command.  After generating the XML file, you can always use a script to get rid off the database tags from the dump file.  In Windows' PowerShell you could always use the following command:

```
${c:my_table.xml} -replace "`<database name=`"my_database_name`"`>" -replace "`<\database`>" > my_table_new.xml
```