# mysqldump with create database line

Tags: database, backup, mysql

I'm in the process of moving my files onto another computer, and one thing I would like to do is to transfer the data in my MySQL database. I want to dump the databases into .sql files, but also have the create database db_name including in the file, that way I just have to import the file to mysql without having to manually create the databases. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

<strike>By default `mysqldump` always creates the `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_name;` statement at the beginning of the dump file.</strike>

[**EDIT**] Few things about the `mysqldump` file and it's options:

`--all-databases`, `-A`

Dump all tables in all databases. This is the same as using the `--databases` option and naming all the databases on the command line.

`--add-drop-database`

Add a `DROP DATABASE` statement before each `CREATE DATABASE` statement. This option is typically used in conjunction with the `--all-databases` or `--databases` option because no `CREATE DATABASE` statements are written unless one of those options is specified.

`--databases`, `-B`

Dump several databases. Normally, `mysqldump` treats the first name argument on the command line as a database name and following names as table names. With this option, it treats all name arguments as database names. `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` statements are included in the output before each new database.

`--no-create-db`, `-n`

This option suppresses the `CREATE DATABASE` statements that are otherwise included in the output if the `--databases` or `--all-databases` option is given.

Some time ago, there was similar question actually asking about not having such statement on the beginning of the file (for XML file).  Link to that question [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935379/mysqldump-without-database-name/13061683#13061683).

So to answer your question:

- if you have one database to dump, you should have the
  `--add-drop-database` option in your `mysqldump` statement.
- if you have multiple databases to dump, you should use the option
  `--databases` or `--all-databases` and the `CREATE DATABASE` syntax will be added
  automatically

More information at [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: That's what was happening with me. I wasn't using --databases or --all-databases. I just put the database name, which wouldn't create the drop database if exists and create database line.

Comment: Yes, then in case of one database, add that `--add-drop-database` option and everything should be fine.  Remember though, that importing the dump file will actually drop that database and everything included inside, if such is present in the computer.

Comment: What version was this for? mysqldump  Ver 10.11 Distrib 5.0.51a, for debian-linux-gnu (i486)  mysqldump --add-drop-database test | grep DROP only outputs DROP TABLE lines for the test database. I have to add --databases before I get a commented out DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `test`

Comment: @jla - The MySQL version was 5.1 at the time of writing the answer.  I assume this from the link to the Reference Manual.

Comment: Note that while using the `--all-databases` option is similar to using the `--databases` option and naming all the databases on the command line, it is not the same. `--all-databases` omits the `information_schema` and `performance_schema` tables. Normally, there is not a need to dump these, but if you want them, you must explicitly call them out with the `--databases` option. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases

Comment: Fun fact: the `--tables` option will remove the `CREATE DATABASE` statement again, even if you have used `--databases`. Happened for me with `mysqldump  Ver 10.18 Distrib 10.5.8-MariaDB, for osx10.15 (x86_64)`

Comment: @RichardKiefer I ran into the same, turns out per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tables) using `--tables` completely overrides the `--databases` option

Answer (score 41):

The simplest solution is to use option -B or --databases.Then CREATE database command appears in the output file.
For example:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword -d -B --events --routines --triggers database_example > database_example.sql
```

Here is a dumpfile's header:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.36-34.2, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: database_example
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.5.36-34.2-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Current Database: `database_example`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `database_example` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do dump the database (with just the schema):

```
mysqldump -u root -p"passwd" --no-data --add-drop-database --databases my_db_name | sed 's#/[*]!40000 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_db_name;#' >my_db_name.sql
```

If you also want the data, remove the `--no-data` option.

Answer (score 4):

> --databases, -B
>
> <s>Dump several databases. Normally, mysqldump treats the first name
> argument on the command line as a database name and following names as
> table names. With this option, it treats all name arguments as
> database names.</s> **CREATE DATABASE and USE statements are included in
> the output before each new database.**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases

---

Basically use `-B` in front of the (single) database to have `CREATE DATABASE` statament.

- short: `mysqldump -B <database>`
- long: `mysqldump --databases <database>`

---

If on MariaDB, see also MariaDB's [mysqldump](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-dumpmysqldump/#options)'s `--system=user` option for keeping the user grants as well.