# create database if not exists in mysqldump command while importing database

Tags: mysql

I've exported database by using following command.

```
mysqldump -u root myDB -R > E:\Java\AkshayProject\Dump\DBbackup.sql
```

I want to import this database to another machine. I tried,

```
mysqldump -u root myDB -R < E:\Java\AkshayProject\Dump\DBbackup.sql
```

but it is saying that myDB does not exists. 
I want to dynamically create database named myDB if not exists and then import it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqldump with create database line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452523/mysqldump-with-create-database-line)

Comment: One way is to use mysqlpump instead.  This adds create database statements by default.

Comment: @Lunc give me example please.

Comment: Please tell me Where should I use --add-drop-database etc keywords in the example I've given in question description?